# What is the best way to incorporate responsive dropdown navigation menu into custom theme?

Tags: menus, sub-menu, dropdown, responsive

I am very new to developing and just started with building a custom theme. I already registered a menu using the wp functions (register_nav_menus etc.) and am now trying to get my sub-menu to work.

What is the best way to build a responsive dropdown menu? I want to hide to whole menu "behind" a hamburger button and then open it if its clicked.

I know this is a pretty vague question but I am wondering if there is some javascript available for it somewhere or if its maybe possible to do with only css!

Thanks!!

Comment: The term best way is relative. But, one of the simple ways is structuring your menu using [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) and use CSS to make it responsive.

Comment: If you need an algorithm, you can, for example, set the negative value for the left property of your menu block and change it to 0 by clicking on the hamburger.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try it!!